# Bounding a complex function from above

Tags: complex-analysis

Given that $z\in\{e^{i\theta}\,\colon 0\le\theta\le 2\pi\}$ show that

$$\left\vert \sin{(z^2)}\over z^3\right\vert\le e$$

---

So I am having trouble bounding the $\sin$ part. We have

$$\vert z\vert = 1$$

so we must show on the circle centred at 0 with radius 1 that $\vert\sin{(z^2)}\vert\le e$. However I'm not really sure what inequality to use in order to get this bound. I have tried:

\begin{align}
\vert \sin{(z^2)}\vert = \vert\Im(e^{iz^2})\vert \le \vert e^{iz^2}\vert\le e^{\vert z\vert^2}=e
\end{align}

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. You can also do the very similar
$$
|\sin z^2|=\left|\frac{e^{iz^2}-e^{-iz^2}}2\right|\leq\frac{|e^{iz^2}|+|e^{-iz^2}|}2\leq\frac{e^{|z^2|}+e^{|z^2|}}2=e.
$$